# Fast android bluetooth communication with HC-06 on Arduino Uno

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have android application that connects and reads the bytes from the Arduino Uno through the HC-06. But that communication is very slow, I need it to be as fast as possible (when I click a button I want to have immediate respond on the android). And also sometimes I don't even get the bytes from the Arduino Uno.

This is my code to connect to the bluetooth device (HC-06)

```
  public async Task Connect(string address)
    {
        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.SetMessage("Please wait trying to connect...");
        pd.SetCancelable(false);
        pd.Show();
        if (btSocket != null)
        {
            if (!btSocket.IsConnected)
            {
                btSocket.Close();
            }
        }
        //INITILIZATION OF THE ARDUINO BLUETOOTH 
        device = mBluetoothAdapter.GetRemoteDevice(address);

        mBluetoothAdapter.CancelDiscovery();
        try
        {
            //Making a socket for communication
            btSocket = device.CreateRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            //Cconnecting to a socket

            await btSocket.ConnectAsync();

            pd.Hide();
            print("Connection succes", "short");
            runthread = true;
            beginListenForData();
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            pd.Hide();
            print("Can't connect", "long");
            //en caso de generarnos error cerramos el socket
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            try
            {
                btSocket.Close();

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

            }

        } 
    }
```

This is for reading the data

```
   public void beginListenForData()
   {
     print(" Function beginListedForData", "short");
        try
        {
            inStream = btSocket.InputStream;
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;
            while (true)
            {

                try
                {

                    bytes = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (bytes > 0)
                    {
                        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            string valor = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

                            public_bluetooth_data = valor;
                            result.Text += valor;


                        });

                        for (int x = 0; x < buffer.Length; ++x)
                        {
                            buffer[x] = 0;
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                        {
                            result.Text = "No bytes have been read";
                        });
                    }

                }
                catch (Java.IO.IOException)
                {

                    RunOnUiThread(() =>
                    {
                        print("Connection has stopped", "long");
                        result.Text = string.Empty;
                    });

                    break;
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

And this is the Arduino code

```
int button = 5;
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(button, INPUT); 
}
void loop()
{
if(digitalRead(button)=="LOW")
{
Serial.print("0");  
}
else{
Serial.print("1");
}
delay(10);
}
```

My code is in Xamarin Android. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some notes. We send ALWAYS a byte 0/1? Why not only in raise up/down? In Android, are you expecting to recieve 1024 bytes and then actuate? I don't undestand all your code but using `inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` looks like if your excpect to recieve 1024 bytes and then returns it...

Comment: Thank you very much for noticing that.

Comment: This library has worked well for me, I recently used it with a teensy to control neopixels https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Library

Comment: I think this is just for the Java, is there any way to implement that library to Xamarin Android?